# How to create a tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to create a tag in Google map marker. I have the following code to display the Google map marker. I need to click the marker for it to go to another page.

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html); 
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        document.getElementById('hid_place').value=html;
        document.getElementById("loc_name").value=html;   
        //  $("#serach_fun").show(); 
      });
    }
```

How can I do

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create DOM element with JavaScript
var anchor = document.createElement("a");

// insert new element into the DOM structure (as a child of another element)
marker.appendChild(anchor);

// set element attributes
anchor.innerHTML = "click here";
anchor.src = "http://www.site.ext/page.html";
```

For more information read [HTML DOM createElement() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)

Comment: I got this error , TypeError: marker.appendChild is not a function

Comment: It means that marker is not a DOM element. The code I've provided is just a sample demonstrating how to create elements with JavaScript. You should know which element you want to add and where.

Comment: So create a element and add it to infowindow. Have you read an article from the link I provided in my answer?